# Font Awesome Icons not showing up at all

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am working with bootstrap and am using chrome.
I put the following code in my HTML file to import FontAwesome.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then put in the following icon.

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Nothing showed up at all! When I inspect element, it's a 0x0 text. No height no width. It doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Works ok here: http://www.bootply.com/mfeJ6QIc5k.  Make sure the file where you are linking from is being loaded properly.

Comment: you probably have something else overriding your CSS, because Dan's code works fine for me

Comment: You need not only the CSS, but also the font to be present.

Comment: Check the console or the network console; maybe you can't link maxcdn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are testing it locally add http: to the beginning of you href value.

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I tested on my localhost, is not necessary to input "http" in front of the link.

Comment: TooJuniorToCode you are correct if you are testing your site on a local server, however if you are testing your site layouts without a local server you need the http.

Comment: @Sean I have a question about that, I used the online version of font-awesome and it worked.  Why wouldn't my local version of font-awesome.min.css work?  I copied this from a previous website.

Comment: @Sean I was able to determine that I needed some things within the Font Folder-  fontawesome-webfont  I'm not sure what they are for however.

Comment: @Paul what does your browser console tell you?